# Can I make nautilus launch Different directory than /home

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-gnome

When we click on nautilus icon, it by default launches `/home` directory which is pretty much useless for me as I do not save anything in `/home` partition. Can I make it launch something else, like `/media/girish/two`

I’m new to Ubuntu so Try to be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Ubuntu Gnome

I made it happen by editing this file

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

I edited this line

```
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
```

to add directory that I wanted

```
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U /media/sumeet/Series
```

in your condition it should look like

```
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U /media/girish/two
```

---

Strangely this doesn't apply to the icon in Gnome dock (on the left). but only in Gnome app drawer. I've managed to pin the icon in Plank but not in Gnome's Default dock. And this is **just** tested on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 and across various flavors icons are handled in a different way

Comment: You can also make multiple desktop files that point to different directories and put them ALL on your desktop with different icons.  You can also put them in a menu if you use a menu.