# How to change the current folder in the current window of nautilus using a terminal command

Tags: nautilus

From the terminal, we can open Files (nautilus) in a specific folder providing the pathname at the terminal, e.g.

```
nautilus /home/user/Documents
```

would open a new window in the Documents folder. However, this always opens a new natuilus window, whether or not the `-w` (`--new-window`) option is specified on the command line.

Question: Is there a possibility to change the directory within a running window of nautilus to a new folder using a terminal command, perhaps via `dbus`?

Comment: Take a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593851/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-current-directory-of-a-nautilus-window  https://askubuntu.com/questions/915455/can-i-make-nautilus-launch-different-directory-than-home?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @JohanPalych Thanks for the pointers.  Idea here is to change directory in one of the existing windows through a command. Second link thus is not applicable. First link is interesting in how it allows to monitor the current directory nautilus, but does not immediately help on how to change the directory through a command.

Comment: I usually use custom scripts for nautilus. It may come in handy: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Files#:~:text=in%20the%20other.-,Custom%20scripts,-Scripts%20placed%20in  https://www.gnome-look.org/browse?cat=126

Comment: I also do. However, I wonder how one could have a current window display a different folder.