# Open new tab in gnome "Files"

Tags: gnome, nautilus, dbus, xdg-open

If I run `xdg-open ~/Documents/` , it will open "Documents" in a new Files window. If I then run `xdg-open ~/Pictures/`, it will open another window. Is there a way to open a location in an existing Files window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A disappointing answer is also an answer: No.

The command-line options for nautilus are [extremely limited](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/nautilus.1.html). The `-w` option is probably a leftover from other options, because nautilus always opens a new window when run from the terminal. Options to open an new location in a tab, or change the [location in a current instance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387251/how-to-change-the-current-folder-in-the-current-window-of-nautilus-using-a-termi) are not available.

The [d-bus interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/file-manager-interface/) does not provide additional possibilities.